# Open file with texmaker results in error but opening the file after texmaker has opened works fine

Tags: miktex, texmaker

I have a small issue with miktex portable and texmaker that is driving me nuts. Everything works fine except for one tiny little thing.

Once miktex opens and is in my system tray, I can start texmaker and search for the tex file I wish to edit, or drag and drop the file inside texmaker. If however I double click on the *file itself* (which I have set to open with texmaker), texmaker is unable to compile it throwing the error:

```
Could not start the command. "../texmfs/install/miktex/bin/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction = nonstopmode %.tex"
```

If I now **close** texmaker and **reopen it empty** and then *search* for the file by clicking "File -> Open" then it works fine again!

This is my texmaker configurations:
[image: *texmaker configurations*]

Comment: You are using relative paths. If you start TeXmaker manually it will use its own path, but started from the file it will use the file's path.

Comment: @TeXnician wow... This was it? This has been bothering me for over a month! Thanks! it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a TeX question. You are talking about a "feature" of your operating system. As you are using relative paths, you are using an application's working directory to form the absolute path. Starting TeXmaker manually makes the application use its own path, but started from a file it will use the file's path.